# Use of skip lock in Report Builder

Tags: reportbuilder

Can we use skip lock as follows in report builder rdf file?

```
cursor c is select * from t where condition for update skip locked
```

I am getting the following error

> encountered the symbol when expecting one of the following:
>                            ; of nowait order

My report builder version is: 10.1.2.0.2